# Добавить два адресса к переходу на js

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

```js
  $('.go-scheme a').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).hasClass("left") ? setMapPosition(43.257506, 76.939267) : setMapPosition(43.231151, 76.899468);
   if ($(this).attr("href") != undefined) {
    $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
       }, 1000);
   }
  });
```

http://implantation.kz/

На этом сайте Схема проезда сделанна так можете подсказать пожалуйста как добавить помимо .hasclass("left") еще три класса с отдельными указателями на метки на карты 
Раньше было всего 2 указателя теперь 4 и если эту формулу раздвоить то не работает вовсе карта(

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите ваши координаты (43.257506, 76.939267) - зашейте каждой ссылки в дата атрибут

```
<a href="#yandex_map" class="left" data-coordx="43.257506" data-coordy="76.939267">
  <svg >  </svg>
  <span>схема проезда</span>
</a>
```

на js примерно так:

```
$('.go-scheme a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var coordx = parseFloat( $(this).attr('data-coordx') ),
      coordy = parseFloat( $(this).attr('data-coordy') );
  if(coordx && coordy) {
    setMapPosition(coordx, coordy)
  }

  /* далее код */
});
```

При таком подходе, вам больше не нужно думать, сколько ссылок добавят или удалят ещё